How to define the reverse of a string recursively and then prove that : $Reverse(s*t)=Reverse(t)*Reverse(s)$?
I was doing the excercises of section 6.5 of the book Mathematics for Computer Science
revised Monday 18th May, 2015, of the MIT opencourseware(https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/mit6_042js15_textbook.pdf), and the second problem is define a Reverse function over an alphabet.
I defined my reverse as:
Base Case:

Rev($\lambda$) = $\lambda$
Rev(a) = a $\forall a \in A$, where a is a character of alphabet A

Construct case:
Given s,t $\in A^*$

Rev(s) = $\langle{a},Rev({t})\rangle{}$, where a is the last character of s and the angled parenthesis represent the string.

However when I try to prove by recursive induction $Rev(s*t) = Rev(t)*Rev(s),$Where * represents the concatenation of strings, I cannot continue.
First I prove the Base cases:

Rev($s*\lambda$) = Rev(s)= Rev($\lambda$)*Rev(s)

Rev(s*a) = $\langle a,Rev(s)\rangle$ (which I believe is equivalent to : a * Rev(s))= Rev(a) *Rev(s)


Here I can't advance much more.
I suppose that $s:= \langle a,s_0 \rangle$ and $t:= \langle b,t_0 \rangle$, and that $Rev(s_0*t_0) = Rev(t_0)*Rev(s_0)$ but I'm not sure what it means to assume this, am I assuming that for all strings of length |s|-1 or |t|-1 , it's true; that it's true for |st|-1 ?
After that I started from Rev(t)*Rev(s) as follows:
$$Rev(t)*Rev(s)= \langle t_0,b \rangle *\langle s_0 , a \rangle$$
Now I don't know what to do with the b in the middle because otherwise I believe I could use the Induction hypothesis directly.

We can define $\mathrm{Rev} : A^{*} \to A^{*}$ by:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Rev} \left( \lambda \right) & := \lambda , \\
\mathrm{Rev} \left( \langle a , s \rangle \right) & := \mathrm{Rev} \left( s \right) * \langle a , \lambda \rangle ,
\end{align}
where $* : A^{*} \times A^{*} \to A^{*}$ is the concatenation function.
Now, we'll prove $\mathrm{Rev} \left( s * t \right) = \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \mathrm{Rev} \left( s \right)$ by induction on $s$:

Base case — i.e., $ s = \lambda $: Since $\mathrm{Rev} \left( \lambda \right) = \lambda $,

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Rev} \left( s * t \right)
& = \mathrm{Rev} \left( \lambda * t \right ) \\
& = \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) \\
& = \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \lambda \\
& = \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \mathrm{Rev} \left( \lambda \right) \\
& = \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \mathrm{Rev} \left( s \right) .
\end{align}

Step case — i.e., $s = \langle a , s^{\prime} \rangle$ for some $a \in A$ and $s^{\prime} \in A^{*}$ with the induction hypothesis:
$$ \mathrm{Rev} \left( s^{\prime} * t \right) = \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \mathrm{Rev} \left( s^{\prime} \right)\cdots \left( \mathrm{IH} \right) . $$

Then,
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Rev} \left( s * t \right)
& = \mathrm{Rev} \left( \langle a , s^{\prime} \rangle * t \right) \\
& = \mathrm{Rev} \left( \langle a , s^{\prime} * t \rangle \right) \\
& = \mathrm{Rev} \left( s^{\prime} * t \right) * \langle a , \lambda \rangle \\
& = \left( \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \mathrm{Rev} \left( s^{\prime} \right) \right) * \langle a , \lambda \rangle \\
& =\mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \left( \mathrm{Rev} \left( s^{\prime} \right) * \langle a , \lambda \rangle \right) \\
& = \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \mathrm{Rev} \left( \langle a , s^{\prime} \rangle \right) \\
& = \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \mathrm{Rev} \left( s \right) .
\end{align}
Therefore we can conclude $\mathrm{Rev} \left( s * t \right) = \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \mathrm{Rev} \left( s \right)$.

Note that $\mathrm{IH}$ can be considered the induction hypothesis on the length of $s$ — actually, the proposition is equivalent to:
$$ \left( \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \right) \left( \forall s \in A^{*} \right) \left( \forall t \in A^{*} \right) \left( n = \mathrm{length} \left( s \right) \to \mathrm{Rev} \left( s * t \right) = \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) * \mathrm{Rev} \left( t \right) \right) , $$
so we can apply the induction principle on $n$. Then, for the step case, we have an inductive hypothesis, which is equivalent to $\mathrm{IH}$.

why can we assume Rev(s', t), and we do not need Rev(s',t')?

@JavierLázaro 1. I added more explain. I hope it will be helpful. 2. We do not need to consider the case of $t = \langle b , t^{\prime} \rangle$.
